# Ext.data.NodeInterface insertBefore is not a function

Tags: tree, extjs4, treenode

I am trying to add new node to tree in ExtJS 4.0.2 using insertBefore method of Ext.data.NodeInterface class.

But I still get the error: "insertBefore is not a function"

```
var config = {
    allowDrag: false,
    allowDrop: false,
    cls: 'myClass',
    iconCls: 'myIconClass',
    leaf: true,
    text: 'someText'
};
var node1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.NodeInterface', config);
var node2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.NodeInterface', config);
var node3 = null;

node1.insertBefore(node2, node3); // "node1.insertBefore is not a function"
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs: `In general this class will not be used directly by the developer.` When you examine `node1` you will notice that it does not in fact have this function.

I think you might actually need to use `Ext.data.NodeInterface.createNode()` function, to create instances of `Ext.data.Record` with this interface applied.

Comment: Yes, Ext.data.NodeInterface.createNode() helped. Now I am using it:<br/>
     var node1 = treeStore.getRootNode();
     var node2 = node1.createNode(config);
     var node3 = null;
     
     node1.insertBefore(node2, node3);

It is working fine. Thank you very much.